# Can't enable MSAA in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, antialiasing, msaa

I want to enable/disable MSAA in runtime and in order to do that I have this function:

```
GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this)
...

private void ChangeMsaaSetting(bool enable)
{
    _graphics.PreferMultiSampling = enable;

    var rasterizerState = new RasterizerState
    {
        MultiSampleAntiAlias = enable,
    };

    GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rasterizerState;
    GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount = enable ? 2 : 0;

    _graphics.ApplyChanges();
}
```

Before I call it everything is normal: the objects in the scene are rendered with pixelated edges. As soon as I call the function passing `true`, the models disappear and I'm left with the CornflowerBlue background I clear my `GraphicsDevice` with.

But after I call `ChangeMsaaSetting(false)` objects start getting rendered again.

I've experimented a bit and it seems that objects disappear if `MultiSampleCount` is set to an integer greater than 1. Singular samples are useless so I need to have a bigger value there. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSAA is not currently supported in monogame. Use https://github.com/SeriousMaxx/FXAAMonoGame instead.

It will provide a very high quality post process AA.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't need just _any_ AA, but MSAA specifically.

Comment: Why is that out of curiosity?

Comment: Your GitHub link has rotted. Can you [edit] your answer to update, or is it unrecoverable?